# Materialize CSS Transitions

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

I'm trying to make a simple login form that appears when you click "sign-in." The Materialize classes for scale-transition, scale-out, and scale-in do not seem to be working. Here is an example of the buttons (the example on their site only uses and a tag button, so I've tried simplifying it down just to that, in case it isn't meant to work on form fields:

```
<a id="sign-in" class="btn waves-effect waves-teal scale-transition">SIGN IN</a>
<a id="sign-up" class="btn waves-effect waves-teal scale-transition">SIGN UP</a>
<input class="login btn waves-effect waves-light scale-transition scale-out" type="submit" value="LOG IN"/>
```

I have a jQuery function that adds and removes classes when the sign up button is clicked, and I can see that it is working when I inspect in Chrome.

```
$('#sign-in').click(function() {
    $('#sign-in').addClass('scale-out');
    $('#sign-up').addClass('scale-out');
    $('.login').removeClass('scale-out').addClass('scale-in');
})
```

The other styling classes for Materialize all appear to be working, and I can't seem to find much on this issue. Any help will be much appreciated. Also, by "not working" I mean that all of the elements are there, all of the time, no matter which classes are applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it work for you?

```
<a href="#!" id="sign-in" class="btn waves-effect waves-teal scale-transition">SIGN IN</a>
<a href="#!" id="sign-up" class="btn waves-effect waves-teal scale-transition">SIGN UP</a>
<input class="login btn waves-effect waves-light scale-transition scale-out" type="submit" value="LOG IN"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#sign-in').click(function() {
    $('#sign-in').addClass('scale-out');
    $('#sign-up').addClass('scale-out');
    $('.login').removeClass('scale-out').addClass('scale-in');
})
</script>
```

Comment: Well, I probably did need to do that too (thanks for the catch!), but that didn't make any difference for this problem, unfortunately. I even tried inspecting their page to see if maybe something had been changed but not documented, but no luck there either.

Comment: I've updated an answer. Seems to completely work for me, tested. If it doesn't work for you, I would test again.

Comment: omg, Thank you so much!  I updated our script tags and it worked perfectly!  Those were set up by someone else on my team and I never even looked at them.

Comment: Next time, you could press Ctrl-Shift-J to open Developer Tools. See this picture: http://i.imgur.com/wUbaiV3.png. Here is error message, which would be displayed if jQuery library could not be found. Obviously, another error messages also would be showed there. In my example, the error occured on the 7th line of file. If this problem resolved, don't forgot to accept an answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Could be done in a more simple way.

Form container - visibility:hidden

onClick - visibility:visible

To apply a transition effect just add a class into the container.

Answer (score 0):

This should work!

```html
<a id="toggle" href="#!" class="btn right">toggle</a>
<a id="scale" href="#!" class="btn-floating btn-large scale-transition scale-in">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
</a>
```

```
let c = 0;
$('#toggle').click( f => c == 0
 ? `${$('#scale').removeClass('scale-in').addClass('scale-out')} ${c = c+=1}` 
 : `${$('#scale').removeClass('scale-out').addClass('scale-in')} ${c = c-=1}`
);
```